# Google app engine integration in Intellijd Idea IDE issue

Tags: java, google-app-engine, intellij-idea

I follow to this instruction : [Idea documentaion](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-google-app-engine-project.html?search=app%20engine)

Number 4: I don't have Google app engine to select in "Additional Libraries and Frameworks".
So as I don't have any buttons to include the google app engine sdk to Idea.

I tried to follow another instruction which tells to install app engine as plugin, but it is not even listed in the repositories. Tried to it manually - no success at all...

So the question is: how to do the integration of app engine into the idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google App Engine integration is only available in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate. It's not available in IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition.